# ¿como solicitar una "imagen/png" a un webservice.ashx desde angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Se puede usar Ajax?

en modo normal lo haria de la siguiente forma

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
          $http({
            method : "GET",
            url: 'http://localhost:4444/WS/wsEstadoReferencia.ashx?ref=VMI17-04635'
          }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
              $scope.imageSource = response.data;
            }, function error(response) {
              $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: actualice el script y el error ahora solo es este

Cannot GET /%7B%7BimageSource%7D%7D

Comment: cual es el error  en tu codigo? por que ocupar AJAX?